# Dojo 1.15 Gridx Custom messages via Status Code from Http Response

Tags: javascript, httpresponse, http-status-codes, dojo.gridx, jsonreststore

I'm quite new to the dojo feameqork. The last few days I was working with dojo and gridx to create a view with data from a json rest store. 
Now I need to get custom error messages from the http response codes and display them inside the grid.

The only thing I was able to do was to display the standard messages from gridx.... Emptynode, load failed, etc. But my problem is that I can only put in some static messages for the 4 predefined values. But I need to ask for some error codes like 400, 403, 200 and set some specific custom messages for that.

I used Google and many many forums, but my only maybe-idea is to use the xhrget.... My question is.... Can I use this function in combination with inner HTML and gridx to display what I really need?

Dear community, I'm really sry for my bad English and I know this question is hard to answer but maybe there is anyone who can help me. I'm so pleased for.

Ps. I use gridx with the dojo datagrid

Comment: Dojo 1.1x was deprecated a long time ago :(  Dojo 1.7 was the first version that used AMD (essentially, a "completely different" framework than previous versions),  I would strongly urge you to write any new code to 1.7 or higher (ideally, to 2.0 or higher).  The current version is Dojo 6.x.

Comment: Hi, im sorry i made a typing mistake here...my version is dojo 1.15.0 and i can´t switch to dojo 2.0

Comment: Cool - Dojo 1.15 should be fine.  Q: So what's your problem?  For example, 1) You make an Ajax call.  2) The call fails with an HTTP 404 error.  3) You have an Ajax event handler.  4) The event handler displays the text "HTTP 404: Not found" in a cell in a Dojo grid?  Q: Could you post a [MCVE]?